# How to refresh recyclerView in ViewPager when we use databinding

Tags: android

**`Activity` code:**

```
private ActivityNBinding mBinding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_all);
    mBinding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mBinding.viewPager);
    AllTypesBean allTypesBean = new AllTypesBean();     
    mBinding.setVariable(BR.notifications, allTypesBean);
   }
```

**XML code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="notifications"
            type=".AllTypesBean"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Activity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:adapter="@{ notifications.adapter }"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**And I set `ViewPagerAdapter` in AllTypesBean:**

```
 public PagerAdapter getAdapter() {
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new CommentPagerAdapter<>(list, R.layout.all_recycler, BR.notificationRecycler);
    }
    return adapter;
}
```

Now I need to get data from network in `Activity`, and refresh `RecyclerView`. But I do not know how to do it. Can anybody help me? 
I have 3 `ArrayLists` in "AllTypesBean" for three `RecyclerView` in a `ViewPager`, and I get them from three `URLs`.

Answer (score 0):

**Data Objects**

Any plain old Java object (POJO) may be used for data binding, but modifying a POJO will not cause the UI to update. The real power of data binding can be used by giving your data objects the ability to notify when data changes. There are three different data change notification mechanisms, Observable objects, observable fields, and observable collections.

When one of these observable data object is bound to the UI and a property of the data object changes, the UI will be updated automatically.

### Read Android Developers Guide About DataBinding

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Maybe I can't describe it clearly.I don't know how to use RefreshLayout out side the RecyclerView in the Layout xml.I add this xml in ViewPagerAdapter in the Bean.java